# Creating an MVC Link through Url.Action Inside a Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create an MVC link via Url.Action inside my Web API Controller

```
string scheme = Request.RequestUri.Scheme;
System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper helper = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper();
string linkBackUrl = helper.Action("TestAction", "TestController", new{ code=code1, code2 = code2}, scheme);
```

And I am getting the error (when debugging) on the line linkBackUrl:

**attempted to read or write protected memory. this is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.**

Is there another way to create the linkBackUrl inside the Web API controller?

Comment: If you are trying to get a reference of the current HttpContext try this:
System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper helper = new System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

Comment: No need to build your own UrlHelper in an `ApiController`--it [comes with one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.url%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for :

```
         string linkBackUrl = Url.Action("TestAction", "TestController", new { code = code1, code2 = code2 });
```

Or on your view:

```
<button onclick="window.history.back();">Go Back</button>
```